# Spring Batch- best way to Scan Directories recursively and store file name in a file

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing

Best approach to Scan the directories and its sub directories and fetching the File Names and write the file name into a file...
        I have tried using  java.nio.file.walktree to populate the Array List which contains the File Name and then use my custom item reader class to
        read that array list and return the Item(File name) from that list as per read method signature of itemReader interface.
    Problem: I do't want to use array list in this case as if there are too many records there are chances for getting an out of memory exception

```
Can anyone suggest me to over come this memory issue ?
```